# Plotting 3D region in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I have three variables, `x`, `y` and `z`, and I would like to plot the following region (shaded) in a 3D plot:

`1 < x < 4, 5 < y < 10, -6 <z <-2`

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: That's an infinite octant (one eighth of the 3d-space) defined by three planes. How do you want to visualise it? I'll take a pencil sketch.

Comment: Well I do not need to visualize the entire octant! You can cut it at specific values. I just want to show what the region should look like. In other words, let's plot the region `1 < x < 4, 5 < y < 10, -6 <z <-2`.

Comment: I tried the `scatterplot3d` but I couldn't get the result I am looking for...

Comment: check out the `rgl` package.

Comment: could you please point me to a specific method as part of the package? Thank you. `rgl.planes()`? I don't think this method draws the intersection of planes though. Also, I do not want to draw the planes, only their intersection.

Comment: I think you'll have to put together the pieces you want by using `quads3d` -- see `example("quads3d")`

Comment: This also has the information you need.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022814/fill-an-outline-in-rgl

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
library(rgl)
c3d <- cube3d(color="red",alpha=.1)
c3d$vb[1,] <- c3d$vb[1,] *1.5+2.5
c3d$vb[2,] <- c3d$vb[2,] *2.5+7.5
c3d$vb[3,] <- c3d$vb[3,] * 2 - 4
shade3d(c3d)
axes3d()
```

The tricky point: the original cube `c3d` is -1 <= x,y,z <= 1. The corners are listed in `c3d$vb` as 8 columns. I converted the original corners to the new corners. For instance about the x-axis (first row of `c3d$vb`) we want to convert (-1,1) to (1, 4). This is done by a factor of (4-1)/(1-(-1))=1.5, which converts (-1,1) to (-1.5, 1.5). Then by adding 4-1.5 = 2.5 we will have (1,4).

[image]

If you are interested to have the axes origin in your plot, you may add plot3d(0,0,0) before shade3d(c3d) - I am sure there are better solutions to this - and you will have:

[image]