# rgl package - cube within a cube

Tags: r, 3d, title, axis-labels, rgl

I'm trying to create a rectangular prism within a cube.  I need the cube to have dimensions of 1x1x1 units, with an origin at 0,0,0. The rectangle within the cube would ideally start at the origin and then pull from a vector variable to get its XYZ dimensions.  The rectangular prism can only have positive values that range from 0 to 1, which is why I only want to show positive values instead of what seems to be the default for `cube3d` of showing -1 to 1 in all dimensions around the origin.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to make this work?

Data example:

```
Augusta = c(0.4, 0.2, 0.8)
```

The code I currently have (pulled from stackoverflow) -

```
c3d <- cube3d(color="red", alpha=0.5)  
c3d  
shade3d(c3d)  
axes3d()  
rgl.viewpoint(theta = 45, phi = 25, fov = 60, zoom = 1)
```

Can I adapt this function to suit my needs? If so, what would the method  look like?  If this isn't the right function, what would you suggest?

Another potential method I found, but which would require a different input and would therefore not be preferred, is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761065/plotting-3d-region-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #Data example 
 Nominal_City_Name = c(0.7,0.2,0.5)
 X = Nominal_City_Name[1]
 Y = Nominal_City_Name[2]
 Z = Nominal_City_Name[3]

 #Bring in RGL library
 library(rgl)

 #Contributor cuttlefish44's code
 c3d <- cube3d(color="grey", alpha=0.1)  
 c3d2 <- c3d %>% 
   translate3d(1, 1, 1) %>% 
   scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

 c3d3 <- cube3d(color = "blue", alpha = (0.5)) %>% 
   translate3d(1, 1, 1) %>% 
   scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) %>% 
   scale3d(X, Z, Y)

 shade3d(c3d2)
 shade3d(c3d3)
 axes3d()
 # Add points at vertices
 points3d(t(c3d3$vb), size = 5)
 # Add lines to edges of box
 for (i in 1:6) lines3d(t(c3d3$vb)[c3d3$ib[,i],])

 #------------Add labels/title to 3d window-------
 # This version of title (commented out) doesn't work as well as the 
 # bgplot3d() version now included in output section below.  
 # Use this title3d() version if you want the title to be dynamic to 
 # the graphic.     

 #Title_XYZ = paste0(stakeholder," ","X, Y, Z")
 #title3d(main =Title_XYZ,cex = 2, line = 2)

 mtext3d("X Var",edge="x-+",line=2,las=2,cex=2,srt = 50,col = 
           "darkorange3")
 mtext3d("Y Var",edge="z+-",line=2.5,las=2,cex=2, col = 
           "chartreuse4", srt = 90)
 mtext3d("Z Var",edge="y-+",line=3,las=2,cex=2, col = 
           "darkblue")

 #
 #-------Create output file-------
 #This section first sets the window view parameters and window size 
 # to what I want it to be.  Then it exports to a location you choose.

 # After dynamically moving it to look the way you want in 3d view - 
 # Use par3d() to get view attributes (i.e., windowRect (window size) 
 # info), among other measurements.  Theta, phi, fov, and zoom give 
 # angles, field of vision, and zoom.

 rgl.viewpoint(theta = 45, phi = 4, fov = 60, zoom = 1)
 window_size = c(164,32,1259,1050)
 par3d(windowRect = window_size)

 #Adding title using a background plot.  This must be done AFTER 
 #resizing the window, because it doesn't scale gracefully.
 Title_XYZ = "This is your title"
 bgplot3d(
   plot.new() +
     title(main = Title_XYZ, line = -10,cex.main=3))

        #a = folder, b = stakeholder name, c = file extension, d = concat      of 
   #all 3 for export
   # a = "C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\Documents\\R\\export"
   # b = Title_XYZ
   # c=".jpg"
   # d = paste0(a,b,c)
   # rgl.snapshot(d)
```

Comment: Where do you want the title to be?  Use `mtext3d` if you want it to move with the scene; if you don't, you can write it to the background using `bgplot3d`, or split up the view into a moving and non-moving part like the `layout3d` example.

Comment: Hi User - thank you for the suggestions.  bgplot3d worked out great!  Adding this to my completed answer now.

Comment: I wouldn't use `plot.new() + title(...)`.  It works here (both functions return `NULL`), but in other cases you could get a warning or error from trying to add things that can't be added.  Better to use  `{ plot.new(); title(...) }` (or the same thing on two lines, no semicolon needed).

Comment: In addition, I don't think R guarantees that `plot.new()` will be evaluated first in the sum, but it does in the compound statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I can understand your problem, but perhaps `scale3d()` and `translate3d()` would give what you want (see: `?scale3d`).

```
library(rgl)

c3d <- cube3d(color="red", alpha=0.5)  
c3d2 <- c3d %>% 
  translate3d(1, 1, 1) %>% 
  scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

c3d3 <- cube3d(color = "blue") %>% 
  translate3d(1, 1, 1) %>% 
  scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) %>% 
  scale3d(0.4, 0.2, 0.8)

shade3d(c3d2)
shade3d(c3d3)
axes3d()
# title3d(xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "z")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This works great.  When you wrote me back I'd just found the scale3d function, but was failing to find a way to make it work properly.  %>% is also awesome - I had no idea that existed either.  Definitely a time/space saver!

Comment: Once I get to a "final version" of the code I'll respond with it.  Thanks again

Comment: You can get rid of the `library(dplyr)` statement; you never use anything from that package.

Comment: @user2554330; Wow, I didn't know `rgl` importing pipe. Thanks you for your advice.

Comment: I have now posted my updated code.  Please let me know if you have any further comments on it.  Thanks for all the help so far.